# Was there ever a type of powered model car/vehicle racing, where the cars were in no way controlled, and were all on the one single shared track?

Tags: sports

**Question**
Was there ever a type of powered model car/vehicle racing, where the cars were in no way controlled, and were all on the one single shared track ?

1. Approximately two or 3 years ago, I found a video on the internet, which showed powered model cars racing against each other ( they 'may' have looked basically the same as [link to tethered car racing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tether_car)  ), but without any tethers, or any other form of control.

   - **NOTE -** My interpretation of this film I remember, has now been solved, the answer below, gave this [link - Rail Car Racing](https://youtu.be/_JJi2tm2u9A?t=35), it was 'Rail Car Racing', covered by dirt.
2. Looking for any type of powered model car racing, where the cars were in no way controlled, so any type of engines, fuel or electric, and any type of single shared track.

   - The ideal version of what I wonder if it existed, I would envisage an indoor single-wide-track,, where numerous electric-cars ( with the wheels covered by the body to reduce accidents ) would keep bouncing of side-rails to see which one would win, which would finish the race, and which would not, just relying on randomness and chance. The answer below, regarding 'Mini 4WD', if that existed ( which surprised me ), then maybe the type in my question existed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be talking about [Mini 4WD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_4WD) world.

It is born in 1982 in Japan by producer Tamiya, and has since evolved and has spread around the globe.

There are [championship](https://tamiyablog.com/2019/11/tamiya-mini-4wd-japan-cup-2019-champion-finals-video/), and lot of enthusiast in many countries.

A couple of manga/anime have been created on the topic ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1h2jaElbMk) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_DKty7cW5I&t=381s) some episodes)

Comment: From what my slow internet allows me to see of  'Mini 4WD', it looks like each car has it's own track,  whereas, I am looking for racing where they are all on the one same wide track, so basically randomness and chance determine who wins or even finishes the race.  -  Maybe they should consider making a version of  'Mini 4WD' where they are all on the one same wide track. - I have now edited my question to specify "where they are all on the one same wide track" .

Comment: That will probably be as close to, or the only answer that will turn up, although I think there are or were gravity powered model racers, and the track is just down a hill

Answer (score 0):

The beginning sequence of [this video](https://youtu.be/_JJi2tm2u9A) seems to show what fits your parameters-outdoor track, no controls. Later the video switches to a more structured indoor track with the cars apparently hooked in grooves or against rails. –

Comment: 'Rail Car Racing' , the rails are covered by dirt - Yes, that is basically the same thing as I remember in the video / film I describe in my question, though I cannot be sure that it is the same video / film. You can actually see rails when some of the dirt comes off ( which explains their ability to turn ). So my interpretation of the film in my question, is based on a misinterpretation by me. My question mentions the film I remember, but does not rely on it

Comment: The ideal version of what I wonder if it existed, I would envisage an indoor single-wide-track,, where numerous electric-cars ( with the wheels covered by the body to reduce accidents ) would keep bouncing of side-rails to see which won would win, which would finish the race, and which would not, just relying on randomness and chance. The answer below, regarding 'Mini 4WD', if that existed ( which surprised me ), then maybe the type in my question existed.